# Create a site using Netlify CLI

Tags: azure-devops, netlify

I want to create a site during my Azure CI using the Netlify CLI. I have it installed locally for now for testing.

When I run `netlify sites:create` I get a prompt asking me for a name, then I have to select the right team. I found there's a `name` parameter to initiate a site with a certain name:

`netlify sites:create --name anewdeployment` but the CLI still requests my Team name.

Also when I first used it I had to give access to the CLI in a browser prompt and I can't do that when I implement this on the Azure devops release pipeline.

So is the only way to achieve this through the Azure api?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `netlify init --manual` option from the CLI, see [here](https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#continuous-deployment) (I recommend the --manual flag). This way you can use Netlify for Continuous Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a site using Netlify CLI

I think what you know so far is almost correct.

We could not use Netlify task to create a site on the Azure devops release pipeline. That because that extension currently supports two tasks:

- **Install netlify-cli**
- **Deploy static website to Netlify**

So, we could not use this extension to create a site.

You could check this document [Deploying a site to Netlify with Azure DevOps](https://codeburst.io/deploying-a-site-to-netlify-with-azure-devops-2743abb61db0) for some more details.

To create a site, we could use the Netlify API to implement it:

Refer to this blog [How to deploy a simple site using Postman and the Netlify API](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/09/24/how-to-deploy-a-simple-site-using-postman-and-the-netlify-api/).

We could use create a site with Netlify API on the Azure devops release pipeline.